# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Mobile Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble getting bootstrap 3's navabar to be responsive on a mobile device. The navbar continues to span further than the mobile display, and I cannot figure out what I did wrong.

The Code:
(HTML)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

         <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigationbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand img-responsive" href="index.html">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" width="320" height="85" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigationbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Getting Started</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="products.html">Brain Seed™</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact.html"><button type="button pull-right" class="btn btn-success">ORDER NOW</button></a>
                    </li>


                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>

The Code: (CSS)

.navbar-fixed-top .nav {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.page-content {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.img-center {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar .brand { 
    max-height: 40px;
    max-width: 30%; 
    overflow: visible;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you in your html code, you typed fixed height and width, which cancels the img-responsive class.
Start by removing that and go from there...[enter link description here](http://www.bootply.com/HwkpQdylqA)

Comment: When I do that the image returns to its actual size and its bottom hangs out of the navbar.

Comment: instead of height, try with max-height with the same height of the navbar, leave the width out of it

Comment: Have you worked with http://www.bootply.com/ before? Fork your code and give me the link to try and help your out... Or you can start with a fresh bootstrap sample and try not to use fixed lenght

Comment: When I have issues with my code, I load the website on a browser and inspect the specific element that is giving me a headache

Comment: Its weird because viewing it on mobile there it works fine, but when viewing on my phone when the site is live on a server it is screwy...

Comment: You have an element that is not contained with a container and is overlaping. Delete an element at a time(the whole content part, or the carousel part) to debug your website. Also, I suggest deleting the padding on the navbar-fixed-top .nav classes in the css, until you solve the problem.

Comment: Ok I fixed it. How do I get my logo to resize itself dynamically?

Comment: I don't think the logo is supposed to be resized because it is attached to the navbar unless you're trying to shink it on scroll, but still it should be in the height of the navbar. Yet, dynamic resizing can be achieved with height: auto; in combination with a media query if you want to resize it for a mobile, a pad/tablet... Could you be more specific?